# Can i change the color/font of map tool tip through arc objects for desktop application?

Tags: arcobjects

I want to have custom format of tooltip of features on axmapcontrol.

Answer (score 1):

The map tip text display is not customizable

Answer (score 0):

On the surface, what Craig said.  But if you are really determined you can create your own custom tool tip class and interface it with the map events.  In other words, you could probably do it, but with a lot of time and effort which probably won't be cost effective for your situation.

If WPF is an option, customization of the tool tip is fairly elementary.